# Python: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append' while using pandas

Tags: python, excel, unicode

I have multiple excel sheets. I want to grab two cell values from a single sheet and make one excel sheet. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
print glob.glob("C:/Users/admin/New folder/*.xlsx")
customer_name = pd.DataFrame()
customer_id= pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:/Users/admin/New folder/*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f,sheetname='Information')
    df1 = df.iloc[2,1]
    customer_name = customer_name.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
    df2 = df.iloc[2,2]
    customer_id = customer_name.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
result = customer_name.join(customer_id)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Error says:'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'

For code : customer_name = customer_name.append(df1,ignore_index=True)

I would like to write df1 and df2 in one excel sheet. It should look like this in excel sheet:

John    1514

Bill    5459

If someone can help.I am new to python and searched the forum but cannot find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Somehow `customer_name` is being changed from a `DataFrame` to a Unicode string, but I don't see that anywhere in your code. Is this really the code that exhibits the error?

Comment: Hi Mark thanx for the reply. Yes this is the code.